# python: how to create list of/iterate through multiple instances of a variable

Tags: python, syntax, marc

I am working with the pymarc library. My question is, how to I deal with multiple instances of a variable, either building a list, or otherwise iterating through them?

A MARC field can be accessed by adding the field number to the `record` variable. For instance, I have three instances of an 856 field in one record, which can be accessed as `record['856']`. But only the first instance is passed.

assigning a variable `record['856'][0]` or `record['856'][1]` etc, doesn't work.

I have tried creating a list, which is shown below, but that didn't work

```
from pymarc import MARCReader

with open('file.mrc', 'rb') as fh:
    reader = MARCReader(fh)
    for record in reader: 
            """get all 856 fields  -- delete unwanted 856 fields
            =856  40$uhttp://url1.org
            =856  40$uhttp://url2.org
            =856  40$uhttp://url3.org
            """
                eight56to956s = []
                eight56to956 = record['856']
                eight56to956s.append(eight56to956)
                print eight56to956s
```

I know how I would do this in php, but I'm not getting my head around python syntax to even search the web for the right thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a dictionary, where you can set 856 as the key and then a list of values you want to be tagged to 856

```
your_856 = {856: ['=856  40$uhttp://url1.org', '=856  40$uhttp://url2.org', '=856  40$uhttp://url3.org']}
```

you can now access the values like with an `index`, here is an Example

```
print(your_856[856][1])
```

this outputs

```
=856  40$uhttp://url2.org
```

Comment: Thanks! For the example, there are three urls, but that number may vary and the values aren't know. If I want to build a dictionary of all instances of the field, how do I capture the unknown values? I'm trying  `a = {}
 key = "856"
 a.setdefault(key, [])
 a[key].append(record['856'])` but that's not working

Comment: For the other part of my question, to get all the fields: ` for field in record.get_fields('856'): 
        print field`